# Calling ASP.Net or WCF Service from Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I am new to Silverlight. In Silverlight, we can get data from server using ASP.Net (using WebClient and HTTPWebRequest classes in Silverlight) and using WCF Service.

Assuming that I do not need the cross domain capability, what is a good option in terms of Security and ease of development?

Thanks for reading the post.

Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just go with WCF ... the model is strong and it looks like Microsoft continues to put resources on the further development of it.  I mean, there's nothing wrong with rolling your own "web service" with webclient either, but I prefer WCF as it even offers other services like the authentication web services.